# Is there any way to get login-user information in javascript (Django)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

I made a `board` application and implementing `comment` function using `django` framework.

I use `jquery` & `ajax` to `GET` and `POST` comments.

Now I want to add `Edit` and `Delete` function.

[image]

As you can see in image, there is `edit` and `delete` button. What I'm trying to do is to show those buttons only for the comment that current user had posted.

This is part of my `ajax` getting comments from my `comments API`.

```
$.ajax({
    url: commentURL,
    type: "GET",
    success: function(data){
        var numOfComments = data.length;
        $(commentCountElement).html(numOfComments);

        data.forEach(function(comment){
            /* Get data from API results */
            var commentUsername = comment.author_name;
            var commentContent = comment.content;
            var commentCreatedAt = comment.created_at;
            var commentID = comment.id;

            /* Create html li */
            var listElement = $("<li>").addClass("comment-box");

            /* Create div comment-meta */
            var commentMetaDiv = $("<div>").addClass("comment-meta");
            $(commentMetaDiv).append($("<span>").text(commentUsername));
            $(commentMetaDiv).append($("<span>").addClass("date").text(commentCreatedAt));

            /* Create div comment-content */
            var commentContentDiv = $("<div>").addClass("comment-content");
            $(commentContentDiv).text(commentContent);

            /* Append */
            $(listElement).append(commentMetaDiv);
            $(listElement).append(commentContentDiv);
            $(commentUnorderedListElement).append(listElement);
        });
    },
    error: function(data){
        console.log(textStatus);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Now, I have to compare current login `user` with `comment.author_name` so that I can add button depending on that result. But I have no idea how I can get current `user`'s infos in `js`.

Need your help. thanks

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are using session authentication.

You can do it in several ways.

First, you can add an extra field in your `comments API` by doing something like this:

```
comments['editable'] = request.user.user_name == comment.author_name
```

If it is True, user can edit the comment and vice versa. I believe this is a better way.

Second way is directly in your script get access to django user and compare there:

```
<script>
   var editable = comment.author_name == {{ request.user.user_name }}
</script>
```

This is not a good approach. Because you are mixing django variable with jquery! If your script is in another file, it won't work at all.

So, I would go with the first way.

Hope it helps

Comment: Question : Which method is desirable way to delete comment? 1. Create `CommentDeleteView`    2. Using `ajax`

Comment: It depends on your taste and design. I would go with `ajax` because users of the modern web are already accustomed to `SPA`s where operations don't require the page to be reloaded. So, I recommend `ajax`

Answer (score 0):

In your templates:

```
<script>
    var reply_name = {{ request.user.user_name }};
    get_comment(repay_name) #call what you want using js
</script>
```